# NLP Bert model to to calculate text similarity, same sentence but not close similarity

Tags: nlp, bert

Dear expert here:

I have a simple program to calculate text similarity. The program is copied from internet. Initially, I have a list of sentences or stored in db and fetched from db, then

1. I make the list vectorizered and convered into bert model's vector, then using cosine to calculate the similarity.
2. 2nd time, I instantiate a new vectorizer and vectorizer only one sentence and then compare against the first time bert model's vector, the result is different from 1st one.
3. 3rd time, I using original vectorizer and vectorizered same sentence again, I notice the result is still different.

Conclusion，one has to vectorizer sentence one by one, not a list. Why???

```
from scipy import spatial
from sent2vec.vectorizer import Vectorizer

sentences = [
    "This is an awesome book to learn NLP.",
    "This is an awesome book to learn NLP.",
    "This is a great book to learn NLP",
    "This is a great book to learn NLP bert model",
    "DistilBERT is an amazing NLP model.",
    "We can interchangeably use embedding, encoding, or vectorizing.",
    "How about a chinese dinner? this shall be close to 1 or close to 0, I suppose it is close to 1, i.e. the distance is very big"
]

vectorizer = Vectorizer()
vectorizer.bert(sentences)
vectors_bert = vectorizer.vectors

dist_1 = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert[1])
dist_2 = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert[2])
dist_3 = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert[3])
dist_4 = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert[4])
dist_5 = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert[5])
dist_6 = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert[6])
print('dist_1: {0}, dist_2: {1}, dist_3: {2}, dist_4: {3}, dist_5: {4}, dist_6: {5}'.format(dist_1, dist_2, dist_3, dist_4, dist_5, dist_6))
   

test2 = []
test2.append(sentences[0])
vectorizer2 = Vectorizer()
vectorizer2.bert(test2)
vectors_bert2 = vectorizer2.vectors

dist_same_string_different_vectorizer = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert2[0])
print("dist same string different vectorizer is {0}".format(dist_same_string_different_vectorizer))

test3 = []
test3.append(sentences[0])
vectorizer.bert(test3)
vectors_bert3 = vectorizer.vectors
print("length of vector_bert3 is {0}".format(len(vectors_bert3)))
dist_same_string_same_vectorizer_different_time = spatial.distance.cosine(vectors_bert[0], vectors_bert3[0])
print("dist same string same vectorizer different time is {0}".format(dist_same_string_same_vectorizer_different_time))
```

/2/result

```
dist_1: 0.0, dist_2: 0.039356231689453125, dist_3: 0.06737476587295532, dist_4: 0.046457767486572266, dist_5: 0.12459474802017212, dist_6: 0.1990041732788086
dist same string different vectorizer is 0.21568220853805542
length of vector_bert3 is 1
dist same string same vectorizer different time is 0.21568220853805542

Process finished with exit code 0
```